CompletedAccountDTO is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @2db52090)
I dont understand this error, the log is giving me a ClassCastException of same class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.exceltic.commons.api.model.datacollector.accounts.CompletedAccountDTO cannot be cast to class com.exceltic.commons.api.model.datacollector.accounts.CompletedAccountDTO (com.exceltic.commons.api.model.datacollector.accounts.CompletedAccountDTO is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; com.exceltic.commons.api.model.datacollector.accounts.CompletedAccountDTO is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader @2db52090)
        at es.exceltic.datamanager.mappers.AccountsMapperImpl.completedAccountsToAccountList(AccountsMapperImpl.java:199)
        at es.exceltic.datamanager.services.kafka_consumer_service.KafkaConsumer.receiveAccountsData(KafkaConsumer.java:91)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:169)
        at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:119)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:366)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2894)
        ... 12 common frames omitted

Can someone tell me why im having a class cast exception when im not casting the class?
I only mapping DTO o entity in my program

Does this answers your question?

They are the same class, but in two different ClassLoaders. When the devtools RestartClassLoader loads the class, the JVM considers it to be a different class than the original one loaded by the app ClassLoader.
